# Obtener peticiones Web Java en orden

Tags: javascript, java

Estoy intentando procesar peticiones a una web pero estas deben seguir un orden. El problema que tengo es que no se realizan de forma secuencial:

```
 public void enviar(View view){
        if(this.numerosPulsados==MAXPULSADOS){
            String URL = "direccionWeb";

            obtenerUltimoID("otraDireccionWeb");

            if(idActual.equals("-1")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ahora no se puede jugar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                URL+=idActual;
                enviarApuestaURL(URL);
                obtenerNumeroGanador();
                this.reiniciar();
            }
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Debes marcar "+MAXPULSADOS+" numeros", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

Las funciones obtenerUltimoID y enviarApuestaURL salvo su dirección y su método onResponse:

```
    private void obtenerUltimoID(String s) {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, s,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        idActual = response;
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SE HA PRODUCIDO UN ERROR :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Por lo que el problema consiste en que hasta que no se ejecute la llamada a obtenerUltimoID() no debe ejecutarse la función enviarApuestaURL() ya que necesita lo que devuelva la primera para poder completar la URL que necesita la segunda.
Saludos.

Comment: @Danyel Melendez Ramirez rechacé tu edición pues indicas que reetiquetas poniendo JavaScript, cuando la pregunta es sobre Java

Comment: Tal y como describes el problema, las peticiones son asíncronas, por lo que mientras esperas la respuesta de `obtenerUltimoID` se sigue ejecutando el programa y ejecuta las otras llamadas. Mírate de hacer la petición [sincrona](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15460793/is-there-a-synchronized-queue-in-java) o crea lo que se dice un semáforo para que no avance hasta que tengas la respuesta